# can't acces ec2 via public DNS wget localhost:8080 working

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

My server is running as I can reach it via `wget localhost:8080` however I can't reach it via my browser using the public DNS name, ie :

> wget -p xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Gives connection `refused`

And it is listening :

> netstat -an | grep 8080

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

In the Security group I've those 2 rules:

```
HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8080
0.0.0.0/0
```

So what am I missing ? The server is wildfly 10 btw

Comment: wget -p xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080 --> have u tried this

Comment: I dont see where u have mapped port 80 to 8080

Comment: @Shibashis  
wget -p xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080 gives connection refused.
I don't understand your second comment

Comment: @Shibashis I made some changes and now wget -p xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080 works. I think I'm getting close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did :

in standalone.xml :

```
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>
    </interface>
```

...

```
    <socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>
```

then when starting the server you might have an error like socket binding failure.
You just have to start wildfly as root ie:

```
sudo ./standalone.sh
```